# Aftership Api with React fetch issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I added [aftership](https://github.com/aftership/aftership-sdk-nodejs) in my react app the following way:

```
const Aftership = require('aftership')('put-my-API-KEY', {
    endpoint: 'https://api.aftership.com/v4'
});

let query = {
  page:10,
   limit:5
};
Aftership.call('GET', '/trackings', {
    query: query
  }, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
  });

export default Aftership;
```

When I am using `node src/aftership.js` in terminal, then fetching data works well (after comment out last line `export default Aftership`).

But when I fetch from `src/containers/Tracking.js` file the following way:

```
import Aftership from '../../aftership';

...

componentDidMount (){
  let query = {
    page:10,
    limit:5
  };
  Aftership.call('GET', '/trackings', {
    query: query
    }, (err, result) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

it's showing me an error in console:

> Failed to load https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings?page=10&limit=5:
>   Request header field x-aftership-agent is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. Tracking.js:28
>   TypeError: Failed to fetch Tracking.js:28 Undefined

Can anyone help me what is my issue and what should I do know?

Comment: That's a server side sdk (Node.js) and you're trying to use on the client side... NOt entirely sure that it will work... You will most likely need to write a small Node.js server... That will also solve the CORS error you're getting right now...

Comment: So I will make a  node rest api with then I will call the AfterShip API on there inside  custom rest api endpoint? Then I will call custom rest api in my react component?

Comment: Yes... that's correct...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem. To simply put this is happening you are using your local development host with third party instead. To avoid such errors, you can use Chrome extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi. This extension will edit response header to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '*'`, which allows all headers on request body.

This is not recommended for daily use, so I recommend to add wildcard for only APIs you would like to use. In this case add `https://api.aftership.com/*` to extension settings

Comment: But If I do install chrome extension then it will only work on my browser what about the production Code of client?

Comment: After completing the work when I will send it to my client then he have to install the extension again for checking the work? What about that?

Comment: I needed to know I have to use chrome browser and the chrome extension for working it for running the app, I mean for every user who wanted to use it?

Comment: @PankajPramanik yes, everyone who runs localhost might have to install chrome extension, deploy it to free hostings like github pages or firebase to avoid such problems. It occurs when you use localhost